# Why does Hyper-V affect in task manager?

Tags: windows-8.1, task-manager, intel-core-i5

[image]

If you look at image you can see that in Task Manager CPU tab.

1. Why when Hyper-V enable Speed and Max Speed same and it does not change the way it change when Hyper-V disable ?
2. Why this apply to only Core I5 machine and Not Core I7 ? I have Core I7 but it display same if hyper-V enable or not ?

Below is the image of Core I7 with Hyper-V enable.

[image]

Please provide detail on this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't be HyperThreading, not HyperV? are you running any virtual machines? if not, you probably mean HyperThreading. From what I can see of your post, you seem to be talking about frequency scaling (changing the effective "speed" in GHz to save power and reduce heat when the CPU isn't doing much). if so, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/565347/how-does-windows-limit-the-cpu-power-options-battery-saving/565352#565352

Comment: I am running virtual machine using hyper-v

Comment: My question is why it does report wrong when hyper-v enable.

Comment: what is it that you think is wrong? everything looks pretty normal.

Comment: Look at my first screenshot. In that cup is always at 3.29 when hyper v enable.

Comment: There is no clear answer to your question. Since its only a 1KHz, I'm going to guess that it is reserved for your VM. Most virtualization systems allocate Hz of processing capacity to guests, so that they can all share the static number of sockets/cores efficiently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processor always at max speed](http://superuser.com/questions/507717/processor-always-at-max-speed), [Windows 8 Task Manager not reporting actual CPU frequency](http://superuser.com/questions/510188/windows-8-task-manager-not-reporting-actual-cpu-frequency), [Why doesn't Windows 8 Task Manager report the actual CPU frequency when Virtualisation is turned on?](http://superuser.com/questions/510243/why-doesnt-windows-8-task-manager-report-the-actual-cpu-frequency-when-virtuali) ...