# does turning on virtualization and hyper-v affect cpu bus speed?

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, intel-core-i5

I have a computer running windows 8.1 pro with an intel 4690k i5 processor. It has a bus clock at 100 Mhz.

When I turn on Hyper-V to use virtual machines, the reported bus speed drops to about 98-99 Mhz.

Is my bus speed actually changing, or does hyper-v somehow affect the readings that programs like hwinfo64 or cpu-z take?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processor always at max speed](http://superuser.com/questions/507717/processor-always-at-max-speed), [Windows 8 Task Manager not reporting actual CPU frequency](http://superuser.com/questions/510188/windows-8-task-manager-not-reporting-actual-cpu-frequency), [Why doesn't Windows 8 Task Manager report the actual CPU frequency when Virtualisation is turned on?](http://superuser.com/questions/510243/why-doesnt-windows-8-task-manager-report-the-actual-cpu-frequency-when-virtuali), [Why does Hyper-V affect in task manager?](http://superuser.com/questions/860328/why-does-) ...

Comment: I know the issues with hyper-v and cpu speed in task manager, that doesn't explain to me the change in bus speed

Comment: What is so special about bus speed as opposed to clock speed? The answers to the questions mentioned about speak about how even the host OS runs on the hypervisor, so naturally it affects all the readings that programs display.

Comment: Because the programs I mentioned, cpu-z and hwinfo64, do show the clock speed changing under hyper-v even though the windows task manager gets it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set BusClock=0 in cpuz.ini and it will report the correct bus speed.